# CSS Border rendering

Tags: css, border

I like to know if is possible to specify the *border drawing style* (not `border-style`) with CSS (I need that works at least on *webkit*).

Well, I have an element like `div.border` and it have four-side border `5px silver solid`. But depending of class addition, like `div.border.red-mark`, it will receive a `border-left: 15px red solid`. I need that the rendering style be *rectangular* and not *adaptative* to line width (or angled to a point).

To clarify, take a look at [**this example**](http://jsfiddle.net/8neN5/). And I need get something [**like that**](http://jsfiddle.net/8neN5/1/). But **I can't modify the HTML structure**, like I did on second example; I really can use **only CSS** for that.

Is it possible?

Comment: you have already proven yourself that it is possible. Not with border style, but you can make a work-around with 4 border divs

Comment: @SvenBieder, the OP clearly stated he can't modify the html.

Comment: @DerekHenderson without modifying the html structure there is no possibility. But there are methods to modify the html indirectly. For example how you see it in the answer from Josh Davenport or by using javascript. Or when a server-side language is used and the scenario allows a post back then you could also influence the html there. That all depends on the exact structure of the project. So in what way the OP modifies the structure must be a decision based on the overall architecture.

Comment: @SvenBieder, Josh Davenport's answer is a CSS-only answer, precisely what the OP was looking for, which is why I was the first to give it an upvote. But injecting content with `:before` isn't really the same as modifying the html in the way the OP did in his second fiddle. So the answer is yes, it's possible, and Mr Davenport cleverly demonstrates how.

Comment: @SvenBieder - Josh's answer does not modify the HTML structure. It adds a pseudo-element, but it's explicitly not part of the HTML structure or the DOM. In any case, it is possible to do it without even using `:before`; see my answer using `border-image`.

Comment: Really I can't change HTML by server-side or JS, only with CSS and `:before` (although I do not consider this a change in the structure, but I must be wrong). Still, thanks for the ideas.

Comment: @Spudley I'm sorry, but that is not completely right. A pseudo element is not part of the HTMl structure right away. But as soon as the CSS is executed the pseudo element is created in the DOM, is a valid HTML element and alters the HTML structure. Only the element is not created directly as an HTML tag in the page doesn't mean it is not a real HTML element that is part of the DOM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use CSS pseudo-content to achieve a fake border, like this:

```
.red-mark:before {
  content: '';
  display:block;
  width: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: -15px;
  bottom: -15px;
  background: red;
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/MnPka/1/

The minus positions are because 0 starts within the border. You may be able to change this behaviour by setting `box-sizing` though support for that isn't that great yet - http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing

Comment: Perfect! It's exactly what I need and I can use it with `box-sizing` too.

Comment: @DavidRodrigues I think I may be wrong with what I said there about changing the `position: 0px` to outside of the border, will need to test it. It's great to be able to use it though anyway :) You'll know the size of your borders anyway so it doesn't matter too much.

Answer (score 2):

The `:before` solution offered by Josh Davenport is probably the best answer here, but just for completeness, I should also mention `border-image`.

`border-image` is a relatively new CSS feature that allows you to specify an image for each of the border edges and corners. This would enable you to design your border exactly as you want it.

Your example would be a pretty trivial case for it; as I said the other answer is probably better for you; but for more complex cases, it's a great little feature to have in your toolbox.

You can read more about it [here at the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-image).

The one thing to note (as mentioned on the MDN link above) is browser compatibility. It will work in most current browsers, but not in any current IE versions (IE10 or earlier), and may have issues in older versions of other browsers. However, you specified you were particularly looking for a Webkit solution, and it has been supported in webkit browsers for ages, so it should be okay.